# What does the dataRowFilter do?

Tags: c#, database, vb.net

What does the dataRowFilter do? is it only a condition for the rows? because adding a select in the row filter does not work

The code is:

```
Dim strExpr = "ClientID>(select count(*) from Client)-10" (to select the last 10 records);

Dim dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = strExpr;
Dim newDS = New DataSet();
Dim newDT = dv.ToTable();
newDS.Tables.Add(newDT);
```

But the code does not work , if I put in `strExpr="ClientID>3"` the code does work so is the `RowFilter` only a condition? because I cant put select in it.

Comment: Think of it like a `Where clause`

Comment: i can put where StdID>(select count(*) from Student)... but i cannot put rowfilter= StdID>(select count(*) from Student)... i read something about it and it is that the filter must be a collumn name and a value only like "stdID=1 or stdID>3"... and cannot be "stdID=select..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DataRowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) property is used to filter which rows are viewed in the [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx). The string is internally parsed into [DataExpressions](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Filter/DataExpression.cs,02614116b93390d1). You'll find more information about the expression syntax over at MSDN when looking at the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [DataColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) class. The same syntax applies to the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h71xaeh0(v=vs.110).aspx) function of the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx).

In these [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) times it's quite trivial to query a data-set/table. For instance, if you have a *Client* table with indices ranging from **1** to **100**, then the following code will return clients with indices **31** to **40**.

```vb
Dim table As DataTable = (
    From row As DataRow
    In ds.Tables("Client")
    Let clientId As Int32 = row.Field(Of Int32)("ClientID")
    Where clientId > 30
    Order By clientId Ascending
    Select row
).Take(10).CopyToDataTable()
```

PS: The same query can actually be written as a one-liner:

```vb
Dim table As DataTable = (From row As DataRow In ds.Tables("Client") Let clientId As Int32 = row.Field(Of Int32)("ClientID") Where clientId > 30 Order By clientId Ascending Select row).Take(10).CopyToDataTable()
```